# Angularjs: Optimizing JSON for managing user progression

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm writing an application that will contain instructions on installing products for work. I want a static list of instructions that can be updated at anytime and am writing an angular application to manage the flow. The challenge I'm facing is I'm new to NoSQL and really need advice on how to organize the data to be the most effective use of the technology.

Requirements:

1. Allow multiple users to be able to manage their product installations at the same time.
2. Track which step of the installation process they are currently on and only show the steps that are possible to complete.

My first thought is to have an array that contains all the SOPs. And then create another JSON tree for each user and where they are with each SOP/Product. Just not entirely sure how to combine the two into a usable $scope item to ng-repeat into my UI.

Any other ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have 3 collections in NOSQL db.

1. To have instructions for each product (whole set of instructions for a product will become a record)
2. User (Each user will become a record)
3. Each product for each user (here it can refer to unique ids of both instructions as well as user)

Angularjs controllers/services can have $scope.productInstructions, $scope.user, $scope.userProudct as data

Comment: Thanks for the notes.  Would I combine the instructions with the 3rd record to show in the UI?

Comment: Yes, you can combine